# Django urls.py: best way to not have a page number in the url for the first page in a list view?

Tags: python, html, django

Right now I have a list view that displays 10 posts per page:

The urls would be something like this:

```
www.example.com/posts/1  (First page with 10 results)
www.example.com/posts/2  (Next page with 10 results)
```

and my urls.py looks something like this:

```
path('posts/<int:page>', PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
```

I want to be able to have the first page of posts also visible when there is no number, for example:

```
www.example.com/posts  (First page with 10 results)
```

The only way that I have been able to solve this is by adding another line in the urls.py that points to the same view and that has the same name.

```
path('posts', PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
path('posts/<int:page>', PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
```

Is this the appropriate way of doing this or is there a better way?

Many thanks!

Comment: like ginta suggested you can set default value to the view like page=1 , if you making pages then i suggest you use the django built in pagination function [django-pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/), it serve all the purposes including your

Comment: maybe this solution :
<a href="?post={{ users.previous_page_number }}">«</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this or is there a better way pagination page:
```

// example:

def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

```
paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
try:
    users = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    users = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'core/user_list.html', { 'users': users })
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't solve the problem, since this only works when there is a number at the end of the url

Comment: okay mybe  this pagination page :
example :
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'core/user_list.html', { 'users': users })

Answer (score 1):

you can set page a default value.In other worlds,if the class **PostList** don't get parameter **page**,and the value of **page** will be default 1.Hope can help you!

Comment: I already have a default paramater in my view, but with this in my urls "path('posts/<int:page>', PostList.as_view(), name='post-list')," it cant find the url path when is something like www.example.com/posts

Answer (score 0):

```
 list view that displays 10 posts per page :
this solutions :

view.py
----------
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'core/user_list.html', { 'users': users })


user_list.html
--------------
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% if users.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if users.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in users.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if users.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if users.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what do you mean let me help ??

Answer (score 0):

sorry,i have tried in some ways but faild.Actually,i always do like this:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/', PostList.as_view()),
]
```

and:

```
# views.py
class PostList(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('true')

    def post(self, request):
        page = request.POST.get('page')
        print(page)
        return HttpResponse('false')
```

For pagination, you can consider to use method **POST**, that's all